# Django, DRF: How to send permission class details while making an API call using POSTMAN?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

```py
# views.py

@login_required
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
@api_view(['GET'])
def say_hi_admin(request):
    return Response('Hi Admin')
```

On making a GET request using POSTMAN with the following request Body(raw/json):

```json
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "example@email.com",
        "password": "pass"
    }
}
```

But I get this as the response,

```json
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have to pass token in headers

Comment: Let's have a look at [rest_framework permissions docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/). It will help you how to authenticate the user.

Comment: By the way, the reason you are getting this error is in your view you are only allowing the **admin users** to make a request to the `say_hi_admin` view.